# Appending to Seq in Scala

Tags: scala

The following code is supposed to append to a Seq, but it prints an empty list, what's wrong here?

```
object AppendToSeq extends App{

    val x = Seq[Int]()

    x :+ 1
    x :+ 2

    println(x)

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the value x created is an immutable Sequence and the method  `:+` defined on the immutable sequence return a new Seq object.

so your code should have x has a var (a mutable variable) and it should have its value re-assigned after each append (`:+`) operation as shown below.

```
scala> var x = Seq[Int]()
x: Seq[Int] = List()

scala> x = x :+ 1
x: Seq[Int] = List(1)

scala> x = x :+ 2
x: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> x
res2: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

Comment: `scala.collection.Seq` is actually not guaranteed to be immutable (for instance, `ArraySeq` extends it). However `:+` is never a mutating method, but always returns a new `Seq` object.

Answer (score 5):

`x :+ 1` creates a new `Seq` by appending `1` to the existing `Seq`, `x`, but the new `Seq` isn't saved anywhere, i.e. it isn't assigned to any variable, so it's just thrown away.

If you want to modify an existing `Seq` you can make the variable a `var` instead of a `val`.  Then when you create a new `Seq` you can save it under the same name.

```
scala> var x = Seq[Int]()
x: Seq[Int] = List()

scala> x = x :+ 7
x: Seq[Int] = List(7)
```

Comment: This isn't good practice in Scala. It should be assigned to a new `val`

Comment: how can we append using val ? i want to start an empty seq and keep on adding values as and when the need arises.